# How to switch between tab when form submitting in same php file?

Tags: php, tabs, form-submit

I have a page that have two tab panel. One is Import tab and other is Edit tab. In the import tab, I have a table that have multiple rows and each row have Edit and Delete button. When I click edit button, I want to show edit tab with form submit data from import tab. But I made this two button(edit/delete) with form submit. So, the problem is I can't go to edit tab because form is reload when I click edit button.

```
<ul class="tab_bar">
    <li id="import_tab" onClick="switchImport()">Import File</li>
    <li id="edit_tab" onClick="switchEdit()">Edit Questions</li>
</ul>
<div class="panel" id="import_panel"> 
<?php                   
    $row_no = 0;
    echo "<tbody>";
    while($q_row = mysql_fetch_array($quest_query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td id='tbl_no'>".++$row_no."</td>";
    echo "<td id='tbl_quest'>".$q_row['question']."</td>";
    echo "<td id='tbl_act'>
          <form id=\"edit_form\" method=\"post\">
          <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q_id\" value=\" ".$q_row['id']. " \" />
          <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q_row_no\" value=\" ".$row_no." \" />
          <input type=\"submit\" id=\"btn_edit\" name=\"Edit\" value=\"Edit\"> / <input type=\"submit\" id=\"btn_delete\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\">
          </form>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
 echo "</tbody>";
?>
</div><!-- import panel end -->

<div class="panel" id="edit_panel">
     #I want to show this tab panel when I click edit from import tab
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#import_table").DataTable();

        $("#edit_form").submit(function(e){
            $("#edit_tab").trigger("click");
        });
    });
    function get(obj) {
        return document.getElementById(obj);
    }
    function switchImport() {
        get("import_tab").style.background = "#8CB3E3";
        get("edit_tab").style.background = "#fff";
        get("import_panel").style.display = "block";
        get("edit_panel").style.display = "none";
    }
    function switchEdit() {
        get("import_tab").style.background = "#fff";
        get("edit_tab").style.background = "#8CB3E3";
        get("import_panel").style.display = "none";
        get("edit_panel").style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```

I already try with trigger but its not work.

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(e){
    $("#edit_tab").trigger("click");
 });
```

Can I make that action with ajax? Please give me advice.

Comment: use a `<button>` instead of an input

Comment: I test with <button> instead of input but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you have any way to create tab to perform that action, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I can solve the problem. In edit panel, we can set simply css style like this

```
<div class="panel" id="edit_panel">
     <style type="text/css">
        #import_tab{background:#fff;}
        #edit_tab{background:#8CB3E3;}
        #import_panel{display:none;}
        #edit_panel{display:block}
    </style>

 #other php code
</div>
```

So now, we can go edit panel when we click edit button from import tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(e){
    // some actions you want to do
    // ......

    return false; // prevent the default submit event
    // e.preventDefault() // or this approach, it also works    
});
```

Comment: when I use return false or e.preventDefault() method, I can't get data from form. So, how to solve that please.

Comment: use javascript to get the data

Comment: I don't know how to use because I don't have a lot of experience in web development field. Please give me sample.

Comment: $('#tbl_act input[name="q_id"]').val()  this

Comment: And how to I get that js data from php variable of edit panel please.